# SilverStripe 3: Add Multi level CMS Menu

Tags: silverstripe

In **SilverStripe 3**, How can I add multilevel **CMSMenu items**. I can add one level CMSMenu item by declaring in ModelAdmin class using

> static $menu_title

Is there any way to add custom multilevel CMSMenu items ? One example implemented by defualt is **"Files"** (image attached for kind consideration).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not yet!
You can add them individually as menu items and use css/javascript to arrange them as submenus under the parent...

Comment: You can use modeladmin to create the parent menu item, say My Product Admin
</n>
class MyAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
  public static $managed_models = array('Product','Category'); // Can manage multiple models
  static $url_segment = 'products'; // Linked as /admin/products/
  static $menu_title = 'My Product Admin';
} 

http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/modeladmin
and in init() in this class you can load javascript and css files to manipulate the parent menu items you created.

Comment: @Know_all That information really belongs in your _answer_, as it is being flagged as not an answer for deletion. Please edit your answer to include it.